# Setting up virtual environment on VSCode

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, command, pipenv, virtual-environment

I have problem setting up a python virtual environment on Visual studio code

On the command prompt, I typed: pipenv shell, no new environment was setup

C:\genome-toolsets> pipenv shell
'pipenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.